# Formatting Text Before Posting To FB Page Via Graph

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to work out how to format text before posting content to my Facebook Page via the Graph API.
However it doesn't format and displays the HTML code instead.
For example when creating the content before being passed to the API I have the following :

```
$line1 = $title;
$line2 = $job['location'];
$line3 = $newsalary.' '.$type;
$line4 = "<strong>Click To Apply :</strong> https://mydomain/".$jobscity."/".$jobt3."/".$job['id'];

$linkData = [
 'link' => 'https://mydomain/'.$jobscity.'/'.$jobt3.'/'.$job['id'],
 'message' => $line1.'
'.$line2.'
'.$line3.'
'.$line4];
```

It actually displays `<strong>Click To Apply</strong>` rather than making the text bold.

Is the formatting before posting the content even possible ?

Comment: You may try markdown syntax, but I don't know if that does work.

Comment: Ahh yes it seems it is :)

Comment: @MarkusZeller 1 question I do have is how do I add &formatting=MARKDOWN into the  cURL POST ?
$response = $fb->post('/xxxx/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);

Comment: Sorry, I can not answer that, because I've never used. Using markdown was just a guess, because it is most widely used formatting without using markup. After seeing your link, it is a clear **YES**.

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned, Markdown Syntax works !
Here's a link showing how to use markdown for anyone who finds this question
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/post/